# минимальный элемент запроса

Tags: php, mysql

есть запрос,

```
SELECT t1.parent_id, t1.user_id
                FROM modxev_programm_one as t1
                LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT parent_id, COUNT(parent_id) as cnt 
                    FROM modxev_programm_one
                    WHERE parent_id is not null
                    GROUP BY parent_id 
                ) as t2
                ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
                WHERE t2.cnt >= 0 and t2.cnt < 2
```

он выводит вот такие данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а как мне вывести user_id минимального parent_id

Comment: добавить `order by parent_id limit 1`

Comment: SELECT user_id FROM modxev_programm_one ORDER BY parent_id LIMIT 1